"Invalid argument(s): No host specified in URI tenantone.localhost:" How to make local API call to a url with subdomains
I was trying to make an API call to a Laravel API that has subdomains from my Flutter app.
Response res;
try {
    res = await axios.post("http://tenantone.localhost:8000/api/driverLogin", {
        email: 'driver2@email.com',
        password: '12345',
        password_confirmation: '12345',
    });
    if (res.status === 200) {
        console.log(res.data);
    }
} catch (error) {
    if (error.response) {
        console.error(error.response.data);
    } else {
        console.error(error.message);
    }
    return;
}

It gives this error:

Invalid argument(s): No host specified in URI tenantone.localhost:8000/api/driverLogin

I have tried adding "http://" to the URL, but it still gives this error:

SocketException: Failed host lookup: 'tenantone.localhost' (OS Error: No address associated with hostname, errno = 7)

In addition, I have also tried running it like this:
flutter run --web-hostname=tenantone.localhost

I also changed the localhost to 10.0.2.2 and a 10.0.2.xx IP address I obtained via ipconfig, as well as other 192.168.xx.xx IP addresses of my machine.
I have tried to add tenantone.localhost in /etc/hosts and also tried adding it as a virtual host. Still, nothing works.
None of these are working for me, and I do not know what I got wrong.

try http://{ipv4 address of your device}

If this is a relatively new framework, and you think the developers are exceptionally detail oriented, try doing your /etc/hosts test against, but terminate the FQDN with a period. Even browsers do this wrong, but most people don't use PQDNs in a way that causes a problem.
